# Maxminds GeoIP php Redirect according to country code

Tags: php, redirect, geoip

I have been working on this for a week now and have tried it with my .htaccess file but even this did not work basically in firefox its saying...

> The page isn't redirecting properly      Firefox has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete.
>           This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accecp cookies.

and in chrome its saying.....

> This web page has a redirect loop The web page at
>   https://www.website.com/row/index.php has resulted in too many
>   redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party
>   cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server
>   configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

I uploaded the GeoIP.dat and geoip.inc files from the GeoIP PHP API from Maxminds website to a directory on my hosting then i edited my index.php file with the following php code block....

```
<?php
require_once("geoIP/geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open('geoIP/GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
// prints the country code  your visitor is in
$my_countriesrow = array('AD','AE','AF','AG','AI'.....ect);
$my_countrieseuro = array('AN','AT','BA','BE','BG','BY','CH'.....ect);
/* $my_country = array('GB','UK'); */
if (!in_array(strtolower($country), $my_countriesrow)) {
header('Location: https://www.website.com/row/index.php');
exit();
}
else if(!in_array(strtolower($country), $my_countrieseuro)){
header('Location: https://www.website.com/euro/index.php');
exit();
}
else {
header('Location: https://www.website.com/index.php');
exit();
}
// the end
geoip_close($gi);
?>
```

I think it may have something to do with my .htaccess file as it includes this in it....

```
# Make all requests have www in them
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

dont know what else to do have already pulled out all my hair on this! many thanks in advace guys!

Regards
-Phillip

Comment: Which page is this redirect on? Not on any of the pages that its redirecting to?

Comment: its on the index.php of the main website Harry!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

Assuming this code is included in "https://www.website.com/row/index.php"

If I'm visiting this page from BE, the first if statement will be triggered, and bring me to this same page over and over again.

update:

Something like this might prevent the loop:

```
require_once("geoIP/geoip.inc");
$gi = geoip_open('geoIP/GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$my_countriesrow = array('AD','AE','AF','AG','AI');
$my_countrieseuro = array('AN','AT','BA','BE','BG','BY','CH');

/* if you got redirected, do not redirect again */
if (!isset($_GET['redirected'])) {
    if (!in_array(strtolower($country), $my_countriesrow)) header('Location: https://www.website.com/row/index.php?redirected');
    else if(!in_array(strtolower($country), $my_countrieseuro)) header('Location: https://www.website.com/euro/index.php?redirected');
    else header('Location: https://www.website.com/index.php?redirected');
}

geoip_close($gi);
```

Comment: Yeah thats what i was thinking lol, hence why i was asking what page it was on - rookie mistake that is!

Comment: yep the same code block is in all the index.php pages on all the sites but its still not redirecting

Comment: Phillip, read my answer again, I explained: if it is in all the index.php pages, it will not work.

Comment: You cannot have that in all the index's. What it is doing is looping, because it redirects to that page, then the next page redirects it again, so on and so four. You need to redirect from a landing page.